# Is it possible to halt compilation if a given function will be called?

Tags: c++

In the library code i'm currently writing I have some classes that are implemented using the state pattern. In order to prevent accidental incorrect use of the interface by calling functions in an illogical order (i.e attempting to write to a file before opening it) right now I throw an 'interface_error' exception to remind the client of the correct usage if the corresponding overload is called.

Ideally I would like to move this behaviour to compile time instead of run-time, is this at all possible to implement in modern c++?

Comment: or `#define` and `#if defined` checks letting the preprocessor do the work.

Comment: you could do that, but it won't look like what you have, and will possibly require templates.

Comment: Reflect the state as a type change return value (or CPS)?

Comment: There's no sensible way, but I'm sure there is *some* way, so I'm not making that an answer.

Comment: A (very hard) solution is to create an interface where there is no illogical order.  :-)  In your example, if the file is opened in the constructor there is no way to have an object without an opened file.

Comment: @Bo Of course I could do that but it would not be appropriate in this case,  P.S. my code has nothing to do with "Files" though that was simply an example of a hypothetically possible interface error. The question is: is this possible, nothing more or less, it is not a code design question.